# Create tree list in angular dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a tree list in angular dynamically. I'm using the [ion-tree-list plugin](https://github.com/fer/ion-tree-list) to do that. I have already created some logic to create the list given the result of my request.

So far this is what I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.records.length; i++) {
    var l1_name = null;
    var l2_name = null;
    var l3_name = null;

    if (data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L1__c) {
        var has = existProduct(data.records[i]);
        if (!has) {
            l1_name = data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L1__c;
        }
    }

    if (data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L2__c) {
        var has = existProduct(data.records[i]);
        if (!has) {
            l2_name = data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L2__c;
        }
    } else {
        // so tem um
    }

    if (data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L3__c) {
        var has = existProduct(data.records[i]);
        if (!has) {
            l3_name = data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L3__c;
        }
    } else {

    }

    if (data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L4__c) {
        var has = existProduct(data.records[i]);
        if (!has) {
            l4_name = data.records[i].Product_Group_Name_L4__c;
        }
    } else {
        var productName = data.records[i].Name;
    }

    vm.tasks.push({
        name: l1_name,
        tree: [{
            name: l2_name,
            tree: [{
                name: l3_name,
                tree: [{
                    name: productName
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
}

var results = [];
var keys = {};

function existProduct(data) {
    var val = data.Product_Group_Name_L1__c;
    if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
        keys[val] = true;
        results.push(val);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My `data.records` is something like this:

```
[{
    Product_Group_Name_L1__c: "OX",
    Product_Group_Name_L2__c: "INT",
    Product_Group_Name_L3__c: "MASC",
    Product_Group_Name_L4__c: null,
    Name: "PROD",
    ..
}]
```

Comment: maybe you have scope dealing problems?

Answer (score 0):

The online example (http://fer.github.io/ion-tree-list/) shows how to create dynamic data via the `generateSampleNodes(obj, num)`, showing it is possible to modify the tree on demand.

https://github.com/fer/ion-tree-list/blob/gh-pages/app.js